# Detect iCloud account availibility / change using Key-Value store only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, icloud, key-value-store

I use iCloud **Key-Value store**, without any container (as I don't need documents).

So the app is not listed in `Settings / iCloud / Storage / Manage Storage` list, only in `iCloud / iCloud Drive` list, like this:

[image]

I really want to know somehow if it is turned ON or OFF, or available at all.

Seems [`ubiquityIdentityToken`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFileManager/ubiquityIdentityToken) is always `nil`, and [`NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification) never gets called.

---

I have a working prototype, modifiy a slider in simulator, it gets updated on the device, everything seems fine. Even though, if I ask for the identifiers (in the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification` callback), they're always null:

```
NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
id token = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
NSLog(@"containerURL: %@", containerURL);
NSLog(@"token: %@", token);

// containerURL: (null)
// token: (null)
```

When I turn off iCloud Drive for my app, it gets terminated in the background. No any notification gets called, nor at relaunch.

Should I simply **setup a Document container I never use**?

Comment: Update your question with your code for using the notification and getting the token. And if needed, point out where the code is.

Comment: It is pretty well documented how to use them, I've already read through them all. Also have a pretty working prototype syncing through KV store. Only this is I can't tell if it is enabled or not using the tools above. I suppose they are not get called / populated when someone not using iCloud containers, only KV store.

Comment: Many APIs are fairly well documented yet this site has a huge number of questions about those documented APIs. That doesn't mean you don't have an issue in your implementation. Post your code to make sure you aren't doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having **iCloud Documents turned on**, I have the token (app entitlements get some new values as well).

But the [`ubiquityIdentityToken`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFileManager/ubiquityIdentityToken) now returns value even if I turn iCloud Drive OFF (!) in device settings for the given app. It does not pulls updates from the Key-Value store, still the token is set.

Only [`URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:) returns nil when turned OFF, and the URL when turned ON.

Comment: You answer gives me the info that I need though I am not with the same question. It turns out that we could use `ubiquityIdentityToken` comparing to know if the iCloud account is changed for iCloud Key-Value in app's delegate before iCloud Key-Value syncing starts.